# Pass a POST request from Flask to a Celery task

Tags: flask, celery, celery-task

I have a long csv file upload task in Flask, and since it's long, I'd like to let Celery process it in the background, but how do I pass this request from the Flask route to a Celery task?

To build the route I followed the Flask documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/

To configure Celery with Flask, I followed this tutorial by Miguel: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern

Based on the `upload_file()` route from the documentation, it would only have one task call to a Celery task:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    task = upload_file_task.delay(...)
    return jsonify({'task_id': task.id}), 202
```

And now the `upload_file_task()` function does everything the `upload_file()` route would do

Answer (score 0):

Your code generally looks correct.  That said, making sure celery runs correctly in production may be additional steps.  You may also want to consider using the  `apply_async`  function instead of `delay` since that gives you some finer grained control over the queue and countdown parameters.